# postgres full text search modifies ts_query

Tags: postgresql

I have following query:

```
select 
  vec.vec, 
  vec @@ to_tsquery($$'fabr':*A$$),   -- true
  to_tsquery($$'fabr':*A$$),          -- fabr
  vec @@ to_tsquery($$'fabry':*A$$),  -- false
  to_tsquery($$'fabry':*A$$),         -- fabri <-- "i" instead of "y"
  vec @@ to_tsquery($$'fabryc':*A$$), -- true
  to_tsquery($$'fabryc':*A$$)         -- fabryc
from (
  select setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce('fabryczna')), 'A') as vec
) vec
```

It more details this query converts "fabry" to "fabri":

```
select to_tsquery($$'fabry':*A$$) -- will return "fabri" instead of "fabry"
```

1. Is it happening because I am using "english" dict while querying with "polish" word?
2. Is it possible to avoid this situation without installing polish dict? Is there any option to just force pg to match EXACT characters? (I don't want to use `like/ilike`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the polish library you can use the `simple` dictionary which will keep the `y` also:

```
karoly> select to_tsquery('simple', $$'fabry':*A$$);
+--------------+
| to_tsquery   |
|--------------|
| 'fabry':*A   |
+--------------+
```

Comment: Perfect, switching to simple dictionary solved the issue. Thanks!